# /var/log/cron.log returning CRON[PID]: Permission denied for domain joined account

Tags: active-directory, permissions, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to get a cron job to run, but not as root.

Within the context of the user (domainuser@contoso.com), here are the outputs of the crontab and cron.log:

Output of crontab -l

```
    # Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
    #
    # Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
    # indicating with different fields when the task will be run
    # and what command to run for the task
    #
    # To define the time you can provide concrete values for
    # minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
    # and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
    # Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
    # daemon's notion of time and timezones.
    #
    # Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
    # email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
    #
    # For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
    # at 5 a.m every week with:
    # 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
    #
    # For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
    #
    # m h  dom mon dow   command
    */1 * * * *     whoami
```

Output of /var/log/cron.log (last 10 lines)

```
    Nov 27 04:24:28 tor-car-rclone CRON[1865]: Permission denied
    Nov 27 04:25:01 tor-car-rclone CRON[1870]: Permission denied
    Nov 27 04:25:25 tor-car-rclone crontab[1871]: (domainuser@contoso.com) LIST (domainuser@contoso.com)
    Nov 27 04:26:01 tor-car-rclone CRON[1875]: Permission denied
    Nov 27 04:27:01 tor-car-rclone CRON[1877]: Permission denied
    Nov 27 04:28:01 tor-car-rclone CRON[1879]: Permission denied
    Nov 27 04:29:01 tor-car-rclone CRON[1884]: Permission denied
    Nov 27 04:30:01 tor-car-rclone CRON[1887]: Permission denied
    Nov 27 04:31:01 tor-car-rclone CRON[1889]: Permission denied
    Nov 27 04:32:01 tor-car-rclone CRON[1894]: Permission denied
```

It's obviously a permission issue, but I'm unsure of where I need to assign permissions.

Comment: How are you editing your cron file?  Are you using `crontab -e`?

Comment: I believe the issue stems from being joined to a domain. I will review https://askubuntu.com/questions/296107/all-commands-in-my-crontab-fail-with-permission-denied and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was GPO related since the box is joined to an AD domain.

As per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sssd/+bug/1572908, the following fixed it:

Edit `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`
Add `ad_gpo_access_control = permissive` to the `[domain/corp.contoso.com]` section.

Full example of `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

```
    [sssd]
    domains = corp.contoso.com
    config_file_version = 2
    services = nss, pam

    [domain/corp.contoso.com]
    ad_domain = corp.contoso.com
    krb5_realm = CORP.CONTOSO.com
    realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
    cache_credentials = True
    id_provider = ad
    krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
    default_shell = /bin/bash
    ldap_id_mapping = True
    use_fully_qualified_names = True
    fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
    access_provider = ad
    ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
```